# Roblox - Call external GraphQL API

Tags: api, graphql, roblox, postasync

I would like to call an external graphql API (without authentication for the moment).
Here is my code :

```
local open_api = "https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api"

local payload = '{"query": "query { post(id: 1) { id title body }}"}'

local headers = {
}


local function craftCall()
    local response
    local data

  pcall(function ()
        response = HttpService:PostAsync(open_api, payload,  Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson, false, headers)
        data = HttpService:JSONDecode(response)
    end)

    if not data then return false end

  print(data)
    return false
end 
    
    
    
if craftCall() then
    print("Success")
else
    print("Something went wrong")
end
```

I get always `something went wrong`. I need some help on what is going wrong... Specially I don't know if am I correctly formatting the Payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your http call, you never return a success result. You've only outlined failure cases :

```lua
    if not data then return false end
    print(data)
    return false
```

So your conditional, `if craftCall() then` always evaluates to false.

Why not make it return `true` or `data` after the `print(data)`? Then you'll know that it made it to the end of the call successfully.

```lua
local function craftCall()
    local success, result = pcall(function()
        local response = HttpService:PostAsync(open_api, payload,  Enum.HttpContentType.ApplicationJson, false, headers)
        return HttpService:JSONDecode(response)
    end)

    if not success then
        warn("PostAsync failed with error : ", result)
        return false
    end
    
    -- return the parsed data
    return result
end
```

Comment: Thanks again @Kylaa :) I was too much focusing on payload. Are you a Roblox dev freelancer ? Because we will look for one in my team for a specific project.